# Diff tool which generates documentation?

Tags: file, comparison, diff

I have tried Beyond Compare, and it seems to be a good tool.
But I haven't found a way to export an overview of the differences.

The format of it should be one that most people can read. Doc, Rtf, Pdf, Html...

What I need is to display the differences of two folder. And it would be enough to display which files has been changed. But it would also be nice if it would be possible to, in the documentation, go deeper and actually see which rows in a file has been changed.

Are there any tools that can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Araxis Merge covered all of my needs.

- Simple to use
- Generated a nice overview of files in folder structure
- Could click on changed files to see the changes in the content

The colors could be better, but that can be solved by inserting a custom CSS-file. :)

Answer (score 1):

Beyond Compare has some functions to do that.

For example, in the folder diff view, select the files you want to report and then select Actions->File Compare Report. HTML is one of the output formats supported there.

Comment: This function only compares content for selected files. I can't get a report of differences of files in folders/subfolders etc.

Comment: At least you can select all files with Ctrl-A.

Answer (score 0):

This script to [colorize diff output to HTML](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/convert-diff-output-colorized-html) might be useful. There are many other tools, one more is [difftool](http://www.arstdesign.com/articles/difftool.html).

On a relatively different note, I had used a code coverage tool that also generated HTML code views from `gcov` coverage information. Its called [lcov](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/coverage/lcov.php).

Comment: Difftool was good for my needs, but it has a bug that it sees files with different names as changes.
My guess is that it looks at file creation date, and when I get the files from source control, they all get the same creation date... :(